Who are the three wakeup girls?
Around the 3:40 mark, right at the start of the movie there are 3 girls that say "Good morning, your highness". What are the actresses names?
The clip: http://vimeo.com/16341338

They are credited as the Rose Bearers. The names of the three actresses are Feather, Stephanie Simon, and Garcelle Beauvais.

Talk about different career paths.
